# Setting expectation on resque .perform method. Task is enqueued in a Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, resque, resque-retry

So based on my understanding, I beleive when you do

`Resque.inline = Rails.env.test?`

Your resque tasks will run synchronously. I am writing a test on resque task that gets enqueue during an `after_commit` callback.

`after_commit :enqueue_several_jobs`

```
#class PingsEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
...
   def enqueue_several_jobs
      Resque.enqueue(PingFacebook, self.id)
      Resque.enqueue(PingTwitter, self.id)
      Resque.enqueue(PingPinterest, self.id)
   end
```

In the `.perform` methd of my Resque task class, I am doing a `Rails.logger.info` and in my test, I am doing something like

```
..
Rails.logger.should_receive(:info).with("PingFacebook sent with id #{dummy_event.id}")
PingsEvent.create(params)
```

And I have the same test for `PingTwitter` and `PingPinterest`.

I am getting failure on the 2nd and third expectation because it seems like the tests actually finish before all the resque jobs get run. Only the first test actually passes. RSpec then throws a `MockExpectationError` telling me that `Rails.logger` did not receive `.info` for the other two tests. Anyone has had experience with this before?

## EDIT

Someone mentioned that `should_receive` acts like a `mock` and that I should do `.exactly(n).times` instead. Sorry for not making this clear earlier, but I have my expectations in different `it` blocks and I don't think a `should_receive` in one `it` block will mock it for the next `it` block? Let me know if i'm wrong about this.

Comment: Did this ever work out for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class A
  def bar(arg)
  end

  def foo
    bar("baz")
    bar("quux")
  end
end

describe "A" do
  let(:a) { A.new }

  it "Example 1" do
    a.should_receive(:bar).with("baz")
    a.foo # fails 'undefined method bar'
  end
  it "Example 2" do
    a.should_receive(:bar).with("quux")
    a.foo # fails 'received :bar with unexpected arguments
  end
  it "Example 3" do
    a.should_receive(:bar).with("baz")
    a.should_receive(:bar).with("quux")
    a.foo # passes
  end
  it "Example 4" do
    a.should_receive(:bar).with(any_args()).once
    a.should_receive(:bar).with("quux")
    a.foo # passes
  end
end
```

Like a stub, a message expectation **replaces the implementation of the method**. After the expectation is fulfilled, the object will not respond to the method call again -- this results in 'undefined method' (as in Example 1).

Example 2 shows what happens when the expectation fails because the argument is incorrect.

Example 3 shows how to stub multiple invocations of the same method -- stub out each call with the correct arguments in the order they are received.

Example 4 shows that you can reduce this coupling somewhat with the `any_args()` helper.

Answer (score 1):

Using `should_receive` behaves like a mock. Having multiple expectations on the same object with different arguments won't work. If you change the expectation to `Rails.logger.should_receive(:info).exactly(3).times` your spec will probably past.

All that said, you may want to assert something more pertinent than what is being logged for these specs, and then you could have multiple targeted expectations.

The `Rails.logger` does not get torn down between specs, so it doesn't matter if the expectations are in different examples. Spitting out the logger's object id for two separate examples illustrates this:

```
it 'does not tear down rails logger' do
  puts Rails.logger.object_id # 70362221063740
end

it 'really does not' do
  puts Rails.logger.object_id # 70362221063740
end
```

Comment: Pselbert, thank you for answering, but please read my edit and sorry for not making this clear earlier.

Comment: Please see my edits regarding separate examples and the Rails.logger